# Package system is broken, multiple errors, dpkg cannot process libc6

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management

This is what Update Manager pops up with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is installed
       Depends: libgcc1 but it is not installed
       Depends: tzdata but it is not installed
```

Edit:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg libacl1 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl
  liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g
Suggested packages:
  debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail dialog gnome-utils
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl
  libqtcore4-perl apt bzip2 ncompress xz-lzma
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg libacl1 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl
  liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g
0 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,304 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb containing libgcc1, pre- dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb (-   -unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6
W: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'multiarch-support:i386'. Please see  man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:
 libc6 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.
 libc6 depends on tzdata; however:
  Package tzdata is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libc6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
 multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6); however:
  Package libc6 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing multiarch-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6
```

Comment: I added it to the main post, since there's a character limit to the comments. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Edited. Also, I was trying to install netflix-desktop when I think I bugged up the package manager--a very weird screen about font trademarks came up halfway through the install and I couldn't get it to go away. Now the first error message runs every time I try to get update manager to install files.

Comment: Hilariously, libgcc1 and tzdata each will not install--because they depend on each other. It's a bit of a Catch-22 here.

Comment: Wow, I must be tired... I missed this 3 times. Try `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb` as this is the specific file that is causing you issues, the package manager is falling over here. If that file is damaged by a mis-installed netflix-desktop for example, removing it should clear the lock on the package manager

Comment: I did that and ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and it returned the same list of dependency problems.

Answer (score -1):

When this error shows up:

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6
```

According to [a bug in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/983543), running these commands will fix it (and it worked for me too):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

more specifically, for me, this command did it:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: why the downvote? because I tried to help? Many thanks!